# SCADA using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scada, glblendfunc

[image]

Supervisory Control and Data Acquisition

There is a way to make SCADA using javascript? I can create assets using Solidworks, and other apps..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said SCADA means "Supervisory Control and Data Acquisition". If you want to create only an HMI (Human Machine Interface) you can use javascript, for example using NodeRED, and it's sufficient to connect to the PLC. Or, if you want to read the data from a database, any programming language will do the trick (also javascript).
If you plan to use NodeRED keep in mind that you can create a complete SCADA system because it allows you to design a little dashboard but also for example to trigger an insert to you database.

Comment: Thanks, I think NodeRed is perfect solution